# displaytag not working with struts 2 use tiles

Tags: struts2, tiles

In my application using struts 2 framework and tiles.
Now, I want to use displaytag to display the data in a database table. I did the following:

in my struts.xml:

```
<action name="users_admin" class="com.controller.admin.UserAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="checkSession" />
        <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
        <result type="tiles" name="none">/users_admin.tiles</result>
    </action>
```

In file UserAction:

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{
    private List<Users> listUsers;
    private String myActionName;

    public String getMyActionName() {
        return myActionName;
    }

    public void setMyActionName(String myActionName) {
        this.myActionName = myActionName;
    }

    public List<Users> getListUsers() {
        return listUsers;
    }

    public void setListUsers(List<Users> listUsers) {
        this.listUsers = listUsers;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        listUsers = UserServices.selectAll();
        return NONE;
    }
}
```

And In file user_admin.jsp(file use in tiles):

```
<s:actionerror cssStyle="color:red"/>
    <div class="well">
        <display:table name="listUsers" id="listUsers" requestURI="/UserAction" cellpadding="5px;"
                       cellspacing="5px;" style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;">
            <display:column property="EMAIL" title="Email"/>
            <display:column property="NAME" title="Name"/>
        </display:table>
    </div>
```

File user model:

```
package com.model;

public class Users {

    private String EMAIL;

    private String NAME;

    public String getEMAIL() {
        return EMAIL;
    }

    public void setEMAIL(String EMAIL) {
        this.EMAIL = EMAIL == null ? null : EMAIL.trim();
    }

    public String getNAME() {
        return NAME;
    }

    public void setNAME(String NAME) {
        this.NAME = NAME == null ? null : NAME.trim();
    }
}
```

When I run the application error occurs in apache tomcat log

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils
```

Who can help me point out why the error, in the solution to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Add [`commons-collections-3.1.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1) to your libraries.

Note that you are using only *one* Interceptor, unless `checkSession` is the name of your stack.

**EDIT**

> Interceptor checkSession to check my log on the website. How should I use.

You can define a custom interceptor stack, and then reference it, or include your custom interceptor AND another stack (for example, the default one) for a single action, like this:

```xml
<action name="users_admin" class="com.controller.admin.UserAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="checkSession" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
    <result type="tiles" name="none">/users_admin.tiles</result>
</action>
```

Comment: yes, i added commons-collections-3.1.jar, but not diplay data.

Comment: Interceptor checkSession to check my log on the website. How should I use.

Comment: I've sent a couple of places and was corrected. Data show up. But you can just tell me how to check the log, or save state in the session log when moving the page?

Comment: I've edited to answer your second question too. About the last comment, I don't understand a word of it :) but it feels like a total new question, and therefore it should be asked as a new question on SO. Please remember to accept the answer since it solved your actual problem (the ClassNotFoundException).